Game Maker Studio Mac-runner crashes with http request (api)
The mac-runner crashes when an object is trying to store an json api value in a local variable.
Create:
request_handle = -1;

windspeed = 0;
winddirection = 0;

url = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=51.5085&longitude=-0.1257&current=wind_speed_10m,wind_direction_10m&wind_speed_unit=ms&timeformat=unixtime&timezone=Europe%2FLondon&past_minutely_15=1&forecast_minutely_15=4";
apiinfo = json_decode(http_get(url));

Async http:
show_debug_message("Running Async");
windspeed = apiinfo.current.wind_speed_10m;
show_debug_message(windspeed);

Json result of the http request:
{
  "latitude": 51.5,
  "longitude": -0.120000124,
  "generationtime_ms": 0.0479221343994141,
  "utc_offset_seconds": 3600,
  "timezone": "Europe/London",
  "timezone_abbreviation": "BST",
  "elevation": 23,
  "current_units": {
    "time": "unixtime",
    "interval": "seconds",
    "wind_speed_10m": "m/s",
    "wind_direction_10m": "°"
  },
  "current": {
    "time": 1713428100,
    "interval": 900,
    "wind_speed_10m": 2.31,
    "wind_direction_10m": 355
  }
}

We expected to the windspeed variable to contain the wind_speed_10m value from the Json result, but we are only getting the mac-runner to crash.
We have also tried to use the ds_map_find_valueto locate the `wind_speed_10m´ value to store it, but with no luck:
var response = (ds_map_find_value(async_load, "current"));
var person = json_decode(response);
show_debug_message(person);


Have you tried parsing it without this: "wind_direction_10m": "°"  in your debug tests?

@TheNomad: As it is a JSON generated by a third-party API, we can't... Do you think the º is the issue?

"Do you think the º is the issue?" I don't know. Do you? That is why I asked if you tested it. I know it's from a 3rd party app, I didn't say to do modify an external app. I told you to do it in the debug tests. Meaning, take the original full JSON, edit it, put "x" or something else there, since you shouldn't remove the tag completely, just remove the degrees character. Then feed it to your request manually and debug it. See if it works or not. Then we rule it out. If it crashes, then at least you know where the trigger is.

My point is, in some cases if you have issues, the first solution should not be StackOverflow, but debugging. So that was a subtle way of asking if you did any debug and it seems you did not. Of course it can be something else, but you won't know unless you debug it ;) And at a first glance with zero other info about how your workflow works, that is what hit me. Test manually with the wind direction being a normal letter and let me know what the result is.

When you say "crashes", what exactly is the error? A GameMaker error window? A native crash with a callstack?

Though upon further review, your code features a number of obvious errors:

http_get returns an Async ID, not the result (manual)
(which you should be using in Async - HTTP event to check for updates on your request)
json_decode returns a ds_map, not a struct
(use json_parse to get a struct)
async_load is a map with general metadata about the event (including the result, if appropriate), not the result directly.

I will refrain from asking whether you wrote this yourself or took advice from a saboteur.

The code could have been something like
Create
weather_url = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=51.5085&longitude=-0.1257&current=wind_speed_10m,wind_direction_10m&wind_speed_unit=ms&timeformat=unixtime&timezone=Europe%2FLondon&past_minutely_15=1&forecast_minutely_15=4";
weather_req = http_get(weather_url);

Async - HTTP
if (async_load[?"id"] == weather_req && async_load[?"status"] == 0) {
    var _response = json_parse(async_load[?"result"]);
    show_debug_message(_response.current.wind_speed_10m);
}

